# how to access the whole cache in "updateCachedData" RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I have an infinity scroll in my component.
and I update the data in real-time using a web socket connection.

imagine I'm getting 10 items for each page and now I'm at page 2.

when I want to update one of the items in the 10 first items based on the web socket, I can not access to first 10 items because I'm on page 2, and with `updateCachedData`I only have access to the result of page 2.

so how can I fix this?

```
page 1 = [{a: 1}, {b: 1}, {c: 1}];
page 2 = [{e: 1}, {f: 1}, {g: 1}];

when page = 2;

updateCachedData(draft => {

// draft shows [{e: 1}, {f: 1}, {g: 1}];
// but I need to update page 1 to [{a: 1}, {b: 5}, {c: 1}]
// so when the user back to page 1, he can see the updated value.

})
```

After reading the documentation and thanks to @markerikson I found `updateQueryData` but it does not fire. what am I missing?

````
 async onQueryStarted(
                arg,
                {
                    dispatch,
                    // getState,
                    // extra,
                    // requestId,
                    queryFulfilled
                    // getCacheEntry,
                    // updateCachedData
                }
            ) {
                try {
                    await queryFulfilled;
                    dispatch(
                        ApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('getOrderList', arg, (d) => {
                            console.log('draft', d);
                        })
                    );
                } catch (er) {
                    console.log('er', er);
                }
            },
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTK Query also has an `updateQueryData` API util thunk, which can be dispatched with a cache key to update a specific cache entry:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#updatequerydata

Comment: thank you for the answer I found it in the documentation. but I'm not sure I'm using it right. I'm in a situation where I have to update data in the list and if similar data dose not exist I have to add it to the cache list. but in GitHub, you said ```updateQueryData``` is just for updates not adding new data to the cache.

Comment: Correct. As of RTK 1.9, we now have an `upsertQueryData` API (same docs page) that can be used to insert  new entries as well.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, `arg` on the second line is the variable referring to the arguments of the mutation. It's used here in `updateQueryData` to identify which cache of the query method needs to be updated, but this function needs the arguments with which it has been called to identify the cache, since these arguments are used to create a cache key.

To solve the problem, use the arguments of the query method as the second argument of `updateQueryData` instead of the current `arg`.

So instead of passing the arguments object of the mutation as the second argument, you pass the arguments object of the query function in there. This way RTK can identify the correct cache to update. You will have to pass the query arguments everytime you use the mutation hook in your code. I haven't found a cleaner way until now, so if anyone has a suggestion that would be very welcome.

```
    getSomething: builder.query({
      query: ( queryArgs ) => {
        return {
          url: `some-url/${queryArgs.id}/${queryArgs.page}`,
          methods: 'GET'
        }
      },
    }),
    createSomething: builder.mutation<any, any>({
      query: ({ someObject, queryArgs }) => ({
        url: `some-url`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: someObject,
      }),
      onQueryStarted: async (
        { someObject, queryArgs },
        { dispatch, queryFulfilled }
      ) => {
        dispatch(
          api.util.updateQueryData(
            'getSomething',
            queryArgs,
            draft => doYourUpdate(someObject)
          )
        )      
      }
    })
```

Comment: Could you share a bit of code to better communicate what you mean?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).